Access Denied: Permission bigquery.tables.getData denied on table bigquery-publi
I am a first time user of BigQuery to earn my Google Data Analytics certificate. I am trying to follow along on a course exercise but I cannot get past the initial steps.
I am trying to view the dataset solar_potential_by_postal_code
When I click on the PREVIEW tab as instructed, I get a red  Access Denied: Permission bigquery.tables.getData denied on table bigquery-public-data:sunroof_solar.solar_potential_by_postal_code (or it may not exist). error.
I could move to the next set of instruction in the exercise (perhaps I won't be able to considering this error), but I would like figure out what is going on here.
Any assistance would be appreciated.
I simply tried clicking on the PREVIEW tab to preview that data.

It's happen to me also, we can't preview table with just viewer role, but we can still query the data.

Hello, Could you please  try to open using the data catalog(dataplex) console, Goto Data Catalog >Filters >datasets >search in more datasets(search sunroof dataset and select)  and open solar_potential_by_postal_code table from table list > click details. In details click on Resource URL and it will open in the bigquery console. Now click on the Preview tab. Let me know if your issue is resolved or not?

That did it! Thank you.

Hi @Alex Marrache, I have posted the above comment as answer, if it addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

To solve the above issue as I mentioned in the above comment you can follow the steps:
Step1: Open Data Catalog(Dataplex) console,
Step2: Goto Data Catalog >Filters >datasets >search in more datasets(search sunroof dataset and select)
Step3: Open solar_potential_by_postal_code table from table list > click details.
Step4:  In details click on Resource URL and it will open in the Bigquery console.
Step5: Now click on the Preview tab and it displays table preview.
